# How to rename a root field in json string without affecting inner fields of same name using regexp in golang?

Tags: regex, go

I have a json raw string

```
{"id":"xxx","person":{"id":"yyy","name":"abc"},"box":{"id":"zzz"}}
```

I want to rename the field "id" in root to "uuid" without affecting the inner "id" fields.

How can I do this?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you do not parse/encode the JSON? As in you do not have a `struct` representation of the data and also do not want to add one? Also, could you add your attempted solution to your question?

Answer (score 4):

regex is the wrong tool for this task. You need to do actual (minimal) JSON parsing.  The easiest way to do this is probably with a simple `map[string]json.RawMessage`, so that only the keys are fully parsed.  Example:

```
var payload map[string]json.RawMessage
if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &payload); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
payload["uuid"] = payload["id"] // Copy from 'id' to 'uuid'
delete(payload, "id") // Delete the old 'id' key/value
output, err := json.Marshal(payload)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
// output now has your desired content
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better for you to write some programmatical modificator for the json object. For example, you could try to use https://github.com/qntfy/kazaam or any other json transformation library.

You could also write some data structure with custom json marshaller which takes both "id" on unmarshalling step and produces "uuid" on marshalling step.

Answer (score 0):

One thing of which you can take advantage over regex in golang is that when you don't have defined structure for your JSON to be parsed then you can parse that in an map of string and empty interface that is map[string]interface{}
Now let's start with initially unmarshing your raw string into such map.
Now you can delete the root element of the JSON which you want to change and replace it with another value and again marshal it to get the new string

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    str := `{"id":"xxx","person":{"id":"yyy","name":"abc"},"box":{"id":"zzz"}}`
    mp := make(map[string]interface{})
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &mp); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("some error occured")
    } else {
        value := mp["id"].(string)
        delete(mp, "id")
        mp["uuid"] = value
    }
    finalAns , _ := json.Marshal(mp)
    fmt.Println(string(finalAns))
}
```

Output :
{"box":{"id":"zzz"},"person":{"id":"yyy","name":"abc"},"uuid":"xxx"}

Comment: This will work, but it's inefficient and overly verbose.  See my answer for essentially an optimized version of this approach.